# Select several items in select option vie

Tags: vue.js, select, checkbox

Is there a way to do a checkbox inside select option vue?
Right now I have the following code:

```
<select required>
   <option v-for=“item in items” :key=“item.id” value=item.id>{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I need to make it possible to choose several options while selecting. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

This won't create checkboxes, but you could create a `<select>` that allows multiple choices by using the [`multiple`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attributes) attribute:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      options: ['Option 1','Option 2','Option 3', 'Option 4'],
      selected: []
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
 Hold down CTRL or SHIFT while selecting.<br>

 <select v-model="selected" multiple>
   <option v-for="item in options">{{ item }}</option>
 </select>

 <hr>
 Selected: {{ selected }}
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

If you want a more advanced control that looks nicer and/or uses checkboxes, you can create a custom control or use a library like [Vue-multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/) or [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#light), for example.